# Swift:How can i set button at the end of View Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

On the button click i have set UIWebView Programmatically.

```
if(button.tag = 1)
{
    let webV:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 80, (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width)-20, (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)/2))
    webView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: nil)

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
  button.backgroundColor = .greenColor()
  button.setTitle("Test Button", forState: .Normal)
  button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
  webView.addSubview(button)
self.view.addSubview(webV)
}
```

I tried to set the button at the end of webView and i am not able to set. I tried many time still i am in progress. i want to set the button at the end of webView that i have created programmatically.

Comment: By "at the end" do you mean at the bottom?

Comment: yes athe buttom of UIWEBView

Comment: Try changing button initialization to something like this: `let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: webView.bounds.width / 2 - 100, y: webView.bounds.height - 100, width: 100, height: 50))`

Comment: thank you alot  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `bounds` property of the parent view to position your subview.

```
let bottomMargin = CGFloat(50) //Space between button and bottom of the screen
let buttonSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 50)

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(
        x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonSize.width, height: buttonSize.height
    ))

button.center = CGPoint(x: parentView.bounds.size.width / 2,
                        y: parentView.bounds.size.height - buttonSize.height / 2 - bottomMargin)
```

Comment: @iron you should put `webView` instead, which is the parent view of the button in your case. I gave general answer for people to come here in future.

Answer (score 0):

How can I set button at the end of View Programmatically

@IBOutlet weak var bottomView: UIView!
 self.bottamView.addSubview(btnTrvalRpt) btnTrvalRpt.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false btnTrvalRpt.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true btnTrvalRpt.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true btnTrvalRpt.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true btnTrvalRpt.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true –

[image]